# 2013 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Cross Validated's [second moderator election](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Peter Flom] [image: cardinal]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4873744203907072/0).

Comment: Congratulations to Peter and @cardinal; well-deserved moderator-elects!

Comment: Welcome on board!

Comment: Congratulations are well deserved all around. I do want to thank *everyone* who participated and stuck through to the end--especially @Gavin Simpson and EpiGrad--for making this a real election, giving people a choice, and by using it as a constructive opportunity to suggest how our site can be improved and strengthened.  I hope and trust all four of you, regardless of this election's outcome, will continue to interact with our community as thoughtfully, positively, and actively as you have in the past.

Comment: Congrats guys! Well done, and looking forward to seeing diamonds after you names.

Comment: Thank you to @Gavin and @EpiGrad for all that you contributed to the election and your very thoughtful comments and viewpoints. I can sincerely say that I would have not been the least bit disappointed if the election results had been inverted! I hope you will continue to contribute to improving our site. Thank you to everyone who participated, too: proposing questions, requesting clarifications and voting. Without you there would not have been a proper election and there would be no site! Cheers.`

Comment: Congratulations and good luck to both. Peter and cardinal look perfect and balanced _complementarity_. I perceive Peter as an extremely experienced data analyst (mostly) and cardinal as a strong austere math statistician (mostly). But the other two guys are worthy too.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to all who voted for me. I am honored.

Comment: Congratulations to Peter and cardinal.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations and all the best!

Comment: Besides congratulations, thank you for spending some time for the good functioning of CV.